# Search selected text in all workspace files without having to hit the enter key to actually start the search?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know how to search the selected text just by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>, then <kbd>enter</kbd> key.
   I want to these two steps to be one keybinding.
    How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With my extension [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform&ssr=false#overview)

and this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "alt+shift+f",                     // whatever keybinding you wish
  "command": "runInSearchPanel",
  "args": {

     // open Search Panel with current workspace as the `files to include`
    "filesToInclude": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "triggerSearch": true
  }
}
```

it is quite easy.  Demo:

[image: search without selection]

You can also save find/replace arguments to reuse and a lot more.

---

This also works:

1. Install the macrosRe extension [macrosRe](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=l7ssha.macrosRe) - this allows you to run **multiple** commands with a single keybinding. [Or try the [multi-command extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command&WT.mc_id=vscodecandothat-dotcom-team)].
2. Make this macro command in your settings.json:

   ```
   "macros": {
     "findInAllFiles": [
       "workbench.action.findInFiles",
       "search.action.refreshSearchResults"
     ]
   }
   ```
3. Make a keybinding for that macro in your keybindings.json:

   ```
   {
     "key": "ctrl+. ctrl+.",
     "command": "macros.findInAllFiles"
   }
   ```

I used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> for it just to make sure it was unique.  But it also works with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>, the default keybinding for the `workbench.action.findInFiles` command.

4. **Reload or restart vscode!**  This must be done.
5. Select the term you want to search for in all files  - you don't have to copy it, just select it.
6. Do your chosen keybinding above.

Comment: This does work with multiCommand extension, but requires the word to be searched for to be highlighted. Is there a way in which the current word the cursor is on (without the word being highlighted) can be searched for? In other words, is there a shortcut to highlight the current word the cursor is on? If there was, then that sequence can be prepended to the above solution you have provided.

Comment: Got it: To select word under cursor, one needs "editor.action.addSelectionToNextFindMatch" . That, when prepended with @Mark 's solution lets you search for even an unselected word cursor is currently on.

Comment: @Tryer see the new demo above.  With the extension no need for selecting the word first or a macro extension.

Comment: Great. Will check it out.

Answer (score -2):

Go to **File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcut**

then you will see the all shortcut with keybinding. 
[image]

**Right click** which shortcut you want to bind. Then click on **Change Keybinding**.

Then `another empty text box` will open and ask for your own customize Keybinding. Type your customize Keybinding and press `Enter`.

Comment: This answer just bind this command to another key such as ctrl + i，when i need search some text still need two steps: ctrl + i and press enter key

Comment: There is no such searching option in **Find in file**.

Comment: find in files ，my mistaken,