# Can I configure VS Code to copy the selection and search when I hit Ctrl + P?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

I really like a feature I found in some other IDE/Text Editors. Whenever I select a class name or a function in Visual Studio for example, I can `Ctrl + ,` and that will copy the selection and make a search in the "Go To Anything" box with the copied text. Is that possible in VS Code?

More specifically I want to use it in the context of "Go To" - `Ctrl + P`. As in "go to File" or "Go to Module" or "Go to Class".

Edit - Clarification: 
The feature I am looking for is actually copy-pasting what is selected on the screen to the Ctrl + P box.

Comment: Do you want to search within all files in the workspace?  Use  Ctrl+Shift+H.  Or just the current file: Ctrl+F.  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51534449/search-selected-text-in-all-workspace-files-without-having-to-hit-the-enter-key/51585347#51585347.  It isn't clear what you mean by "in the context of 'Go To'?  Do you want to use Ctrl+P instead of Ctrl+Shift+H?

Comment: Thanks I will edit the question so it's more clear

Comment: I'm not sure how to do *exactly* what you want, but I think "Go to Definition" (ctrl+ F12) may at least get you half-way there. If you have file named for some string, I bet it contains the definition.